# adding jars in classpath executing the main java class in unix

Tags: java, unix

I have a jar the below location the name of the jar is bce_boa.jar and it containg a class that has main method in it 
the name of the class is DummyRmiSecurity.java

```
/opt/app/pracier/servers/clsintegration/racier_14_1_/ops/lib/bce_boa.jar
```

now when i am this above location i executed the below command in unix to execute DummyRmiSecurity which is in bce_boa.jar

```
java -cp  /opt/app/pracier/servers/clsintegration/racier_14_1_/ops/lib/bce_boa.jar  com.jms.rmisecurity.DummyRmiSecurity
```

but i get the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
```

now upon analysis i come to know that i get this error when spring jars are not included in the class path so my all spring related jars are the below location itself

```
/opt/app/pracier/servers/clsintegration/racier_14_1_/ops/lib
```

now please advise how can i include all jars of the above location in my classpath itself

Comment: You should be using `java -jar` for this, with the `Class-path` specified in the manifest of the main JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` in the classpath to include all `.jar` files in a given directory, but you need to take care to protect the `*` from expansion by your shell.

```
java -cp  '/opt/app/pracier/servers/clsintegration/racier_14_1_/ops/lib/*'  com.jms.rmisecurity.DummyRmiSecurity
```

Without the quotes, the shell would expand the wildcard and try to pass a space-separated list of file names to `java`, which would not work.  The `java` command needs to see the literal `*` itself.

Answer (score 0):

If /opt/app/pracier/servers/clsintegration/racier_14_1_/ops/lib contains all necessary libraries you need to add this to your classpath. Command should look like this

```
java -cp  "/opt/app/pracier/servers/clsintegration/racier_14_1_/ops/lib/bce_boa.jar:/opt/app/pracier/servers/clsintegration/racier_14_1_/ops/lib/*"  com.jms.rmisecurity.DummyRmiSecurity
```

EDIT: I didn't noticed that bce_boa is in same folder that other libs, that case Ian Roberts answer is better.